# How to syntax check export key value data

Tags: java, export, environment-variables

I am allowing users to define their own user data in a format like:

```
export k0=v0;
export k1="v 1";
```

For all the value fields, I want them all to be double quoted. For example, output of the above case would be:

```
export k0="v0";
export k1="v 1";
```

I am doing this in order to make sure users will be able to allow SPACE in their value fields.

Is there a `Java` library that checks the correctness of each line of input?

This is needed since if an input looks like:

```
export k2="v2;
```

It will take this as an error input since it doesn't have a close double quote.

Comment: You will have to write your own parser for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple regex to validate your double quoted input:

```
private static final String PATTERN_EXPORT = "\\\".*\\\"";
```

Explanation of this regex:

```
\\\" ---> begin quote(escaped)
.*   ---> anything 
\\\" ---> final quote(escaped)
```

Finally, You create an utility method to validate your input:

```
private static boolean validateInput(String text) {
    if (text != null) {
        return text.matches(PATTERN_DOUBLE_QUOTED);
    }
    return false;
}
```

EX:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String k0="\"v0\"";
    String k1="\"v 1\"";
    String k2="\"v2 ";

    System.out.println("export k0 =" + k0 + " is valid : " + validateInput(k0));
    System.out.println("export k1 =" + k1 + " is valid : " + validateInput(k1));
    System.out.println("export k2 =" + k2 + " is valid : " + validateInput(k2));
}
```

The Output:

```
export k0 ="v0" is valid : true
export k1 ="v 1" is valid : true
export k2 ="v2  is valid : false
```

Your principal propose is validate the value of your key (export), I don't know how do you get this value (file, properties file, data base, user input, etc), in all the cases, your principal propose is validate the value for this key.

If you need a regex for all your line :

```
private static final String PATTERN_DOUBLE_QUOTED = "export .[^\\s-]*\\=\\\".*\\\"";
```

Explanation

```
export  ------>begin
.[^\\s-]*   ---> text without white space
\\=  ---> = (escaped)
\\\" ---> begin quote(escaped)
.*   ---> anything 
\\\"    ---> final quote(escaped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's something which can do that for you.
You should write your own parser/regex

The issue is that Conditional expressions are not supported by java.util.regex.Pattern class. To get around that you could use a 3rd party regexp library such as JRegex

In any case you can do something in regex.
Have a look at this code i wrote for your input. This is not optimal but it's something you can start with it.
The idea is to check  it with 2 different patterns.
Only one of those patterns should match.
Of course test my code with more samples...

```
private final static String regexNoQuotes =  "(\\s)*export(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\s)*";
private final static String regexWithQuotes = "(\\s)*export(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*\"(\\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]+(\\s)*\"(\\s)*";

private static boolean checkExportStatement(String str){
  return str.matches(regexNoQuotes) ^ str.matches(regexWithQuotes);
}
```